# Unstable BLE mesh + WiFi in ESP32-C3

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, esp32

ESP32-C3, idf v4.4
I am deveploping a BLE gateway for smarthome and do same test cases

Case test 1st: 1 LPN sensor + 1 gateway ( BLE + WiFi) -> event of sensor are not stable, miss message frequently

Case test 2nd: 1 LPN sensor+ 1 gateway (BLE only) -> event of sensor are stable

Case test 3rd: 1 LPN sensor + 1 normal BLE node (switch, light) + 1 gateway( BLE + WiFi) -> event of sensor are stable

I think the problem here is the coexistence of BLE and WiFi. Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: This is the [expected behaviour](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-guides/coexist.html#how-to-use-the-coexistence-feature) when BLE and WiFi use the same hardware. However, have you tried optimising your firmware (as described in the documentation) to get better results?

Comment: There is no "coexistence" of BLE and WiFi, both share the same RF circuitry and antenna, when you using WiFi, BLE doesn't work and when you using BLE, WiFi doesn't work, you need to manually manage that, or alternatively for better performance, separate the mesh controller from a dedicate WiFi Gateway with two devices.

Comment: All Espressif chips supporting both BLE and WiFi using the same antenna has a feature called "coexistence" which time schedules the antenna resources. BLE mesh uses BLE scanning, which makes heavy use of the antenna, so it can indeed clash with WiFi. You can try different power saving modes maybe for the wifi.